# UDP port ranges in WebRTC application

Tags: python, containers, udp, webrtc, aiortc

I am using a video streaming application that uses WebRTC inside Docker containers. The challenge I'm facing is with the firewall configuration because the application seems to pick UDP ports at random for the video streams, which use the RTP and RTCP protocols. For easier firewall rule management and to conveniently expose the right ports on the Docker containers, I need to lock down the application to a specific range of UDP ports. This way, I can set up the firewall rules just once and not worry about random ports anymore. The application is built on the [aiortc](https://github.com/aiortc/aiortc) library.

I found out this guy who tried to work on but could not get it [restrict-port-range](https://github.com/sirf/aioice/tree/restrict-port-range)